# connecting to wifi but don't see anything in phone

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi

i'm trying to connect to a WIFI point , 
when i run the code and look at the logs, i do get the "connected to wifi point"
log message, so in theory i'm connected, 
but in my phone i don't get a connected sign , 
and it looks as though i'm not connected to a WIFI,
what could be the problem for this ?

i'm using this function to connect to a remote WIFI point,

```
public void connectToNetwork (String ssidName, String netPassword) {

        Log.d("mtAppLogs", "initlizing search");

        String networkSSID = ssidName;
        String networkPass = netPassword;

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain
        conf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            Log.d("mtAppLogs", "initlizing wifi Point");
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                Log.d("mtAppLogs", "foundWifiPiont");
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                Log.d("mtAppLogs", "connected to wifi point");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

i'm using these permissions for my class >

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: `connect to a WIFI point in android studio`. Why would Android Studio try to connect to a wifi point?

Comment: what ? i'm trying it in my phone...i'm just using Android studio as an ide... i thought it's obvious..

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your ide. So do not mention it with a tag either.